# DevArt dotConnect for PostgreSQL Entity Framework execute function without import not populating class properties

Tags: sql, entity-framework, postgresql, devart, dotconnect

I have following POCO class against database table

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

A function in PostgreSQL database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_proc_pg()
  RETURNS TABLE(id integer, name character varying, Checked boolean, Mobile character varying, Email character varying) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY select temp1.id, temp1.Name, temp1.Checked, temp1.Mobile, temp1.Email from temp1;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Defined a generic function to call PostgreSQL function and get back data

```
public static List<T> ExecuteProc<T>(string procname, params PgSqlParameter[] param)
{
    List<T> list;
    string paranames = string.Empty;
    foreach (PgSqlParameter p in param)
    {
    if (paranames != string.Empty)
        paranames += ", ";
    paranames = paranames + "?";
    }

    using (var context  = new EntityContext())
    {
    list = context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("select " + procname + "(" + paranames + ")", param).ToList<T>();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Calling above function in Controller

```
public ActionResult ProcTest()
{
    List<Contact> contacts = DAL.ExecuteProc<Contact>("test_proc_pg");
    return View(contacts);
}
```

Function is executing and returning `List<Contact>` but all the fields in class are `null`.

```
{TestPG.Models.Contact}
    Checked: false
    Email: null
    Id: 0
    Mobile: null
    Name: null
```

However if i use SQL Server/SqlClient and call proc similarly it is populating all fields. Here is  similar function written for SQL Server

```
public static List<T> ExecuteProc<T>(string procname, params SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        List<T> list;
        string paranames = string.Empty;
        foreach (SqlParameter p in param)
        {
            if (paranames != string.Empty)
                paranames += ", ";
            paranames = paranames + "@" + p.ParameterName;
        }

        using (var context = new SSContext())
        {
            list = context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("exec " + procname + " " + paranames, param).ToList<T>();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

When i call it from controller it gives class with all fields populated

```
public ActionResult ProcTest()
    {
        List<Contact> contacts = DAL.ExecuteProc<Contact>("test_proc_ss");
        return View(contacts);
    }
```

Here is result from SQL Server

```
{TestSS.Models.Contact}
    Checked: false
    Email: "noone@nowhere.com"
    Id: 1
    Mobile: "1234567890"
    Name: "samtech"
```

What the wrong i am doing with dotConnect PostgreSQL?

I am using EF6 with latest trial version of dotConnect for PostgreSQL. I do not want to import functions.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have answered to you at our forum: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29126

**ANSWER:**

Please change this code

```
list = context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("select " + procname + "(" + paranames + ")", param).ToList<T>();
```

with this:

```
list = context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("select * from " + procname + "(" + paranames + ")", param).ToList<T>();
```

This is related to the peculiarity of working with the PostgreSQL stored procedures. In case of "select test_proc_ss" the PostgreSQL record is returned. It is necessary to disclose the query, so that all columns are returned and EF could materialize the corresponding objects.

Comment: Thanks! the solution you provided is working very well.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the answer here.